# Nfc-V tag reading example?

Tags: android, nfc, iso-15693

Could somebody provide an NFC-V tag reading example code?
Android Development Guide provides only the NFCDemo code that is for NDEF tag only. There are no resources for all the other kinds of tags. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Reading block 0 demo working for an 15693 i-code sli

```
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

out.write(new byte[] { (byte)0x20, (byte)0x20 }); //addressed mode,  read single blocks,  
out.write(nfcV_tag.getTag().getId()); //address
out.write(new byte[] { (byte)blockIndex }); //block 0

byte errorcode_and_block0[] = nfcV_tag.transceive(out.toByteArray());
//1st byte should be 0 if everything is ok. next 4 bytes are block 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Well - With Android 2.3.4 you can use the ordinary NDEF format and use the usual android API to write to the tag just like any other ndef complient tag. NFC-V has been the major feature for Android 2.3.4 after all.

If you otherwise want to communicate with the NFC-V tag: It's nothing more then the ISO 15693 standard. You should be able to find the PDUs that this tag understands with a google-search and then you can roll your own implementation if you really want.